# How to add cryptsetup to Dracut

Tags: dracut, rescuemode

I'm switching to Dracut and I've numerous problems. In order to eliminate them one by one, first I want my system to boot correctly. So my Grub2 entry looks like this:

```
menuentry 'dracut' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  829c0201-9b6d-4e18-8464-9d2551311ea6
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 829c0201-9b6d-4e18-8464-9d2551311ea6
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.9.0-2-amd64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.9.0-2-amd64 rd.shell rd.debug log_buf_len=1M
        echo    'Loading dracut initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-4.9.0-2-amd64.img
}
```

I expect to be dropped into the rescue shell and then manually assemble the root file system, and continue booting; but there is no `cryptsetup` binary in the rescue shell.

Dracut configuration file `/etc/dracut.conf.d/*` looks like this:

```
do_prelink=no
add_dracutmodule+="cryptsetup"
```

Relevant list of modules are as follows:

```
# dracut --list-modules | grep crypt
dracut: Executing: /usr/bin/dracut --list-modules
crypt
crypt-gpg
crypt-loop
ecryptfs
```

How can I add `cryptsetup` so I could manually unlock the encrypted partition manually (via rescue shell)?

Answer (score 3):

as of debian dracut-core 044+243-3, /usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/90crypt/module-setup.sh:

```
require_any_binary $systemdutildir/systemd-cryptsetup cryptsetup || return 1
```

so dracut first tries to include /lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup, if the first not exist then include /sbin/cryptsetup, if neither then fail.

these are each provided by cryptsetup-bin 2:2.1.0-5 and systemd 241-1, respectively.

the usage of /lib/systemd/systemd-cryptsetup is not very same as /sbin/cryptsetup. indeed, it has less functionality:

```
systemd-cryptsetup attach VOLUME SOURCEDEVICE [PASSWORD] [OPTIONS]
systemd-cryptsetup detach VOLUME

Attaches or detaches an encrypted block device.

See the systemd-cryptsetup@.service(8) man page for details.
```

so we may want include /sbin/cryptsetup by

```
dracut --install "/sbin/cryptsetup" /boot/initrd.1 4.19.0-5-amd64
```

or in /etc/dracut.conf.d/XXX

```
install_items+="/sbin/cryptsetup"
```

there are also "include" switches that copy only the file itself, while "install" switches also copy dynamic libraries.

finally, verify the inclusion: `lsinitrd /boot/initrd.1`.

output (maybe with `|grep cryptsetup`):

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root     root        47152 Jul  3 09:10 sbin/cryptsetup  
-rw-r--r--   1 root     root       363920 Feb  9 07:40 lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcryptsetup.so.12.4.0
```